# ViewPager inside ViewPager.How to scroll parent pager horizontally instead of scrolling child, but keep child pager vertical scroll?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager, android-scrollview

I have a parent `ViewPager`, each page of which contains a child `ViewPager`.
Child `ViewPager` may contain a `ListView` or a vertical `ScrollView`.
I want to pass horizontal scroll from child `ViewPager` to parent `ViewPager`, but want to keep child `ViewPager` scrollable vertical.

Overriding `dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` in child ViewPager and returning `false` helps to pass motion events to parent ViewPager, but how to keep `ListView` and `ScrollView` in child `ViewPager` scrollable?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The solution was easier than I expected.

Just override `canScrollHorizontally` in child ViewPager and return false.

Comment: This is so useful if you had a parent horizontal viewpager and a vertical viewpager in one of the parent viewpager fragments! Override this in the child vertical viewpager and you are good to go! This is so useful!

Comment: Thank you very very much, you just saved my life after working on this problem for hours.

Comment: Thanks very muuuuuuuuuch!

Comment: That was brilliant

Comment: I know we are not supposed to write thanks in comments, but this is fantastic!! Saved me tons of work comparing to other solutions!! Thanks again!!!!!!!