# ViewPager from last banner image page to first banner Image page wit

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a Activity with a view pager for sliding with the four fragment in 1st Fragment I have one more view pager for banner and its getting dynamic
image from api but when I am going to last page of banner Image and when slide right it goes to next fagment, I want to make banner Image from last to first page of image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqxFH.jpg) 
In  activity for fragment slide view pager

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/vpPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

In Fragment for banner Image using viewPager

`<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                        android:id="@+id/bannerPager"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="200dp" />`

I have attached screenshot as well, I want to go from last banner image to first banner image please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting this:

```
viewPager.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
```

or try this [ViewPager inside ViewPager.How to scroll parent pager horizontally instead of scrolling child, but keep child pager vertical scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33463804/viewpager-inside-viewpager-how-to-scroll-parent-pager-horizontally-instead-of-sc)

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is not working, I have to go from last banner page to first banner page

Comment: You want it to repeat again?

Comment: Yes I want to repeat againg for banner viewPager and I have use bannerPager.addOnPageChangeListener in that I have given this public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                if (myPager.getCurrentItem() == bannerList.size() - 1) {
                    myPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
                }
            } ,   but its not working proper , If i am going from at last page its automatically scroll to first page

Comment: Thanks Sarthak, its work but I use this link its working proper  https://github.com/waylife/InfiniteViewPager